# Display SpatialPolygonsDataFrame on leaflet map with R

Tags: r, leaflet, polygon

I would like to display the polygon of Canada on a leaflet map.

```
# create map
library(leaflet)
m = leaflet() %>% addTiles()
m
```

I was able to find the polygon for Canada: http://www.gadm.org/country.
I chose the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame format for R, but there are other formats available (such as Shapefile)

```
# load object in R
load("country_polygons/CAN_adm0.RData")
pol_can <- gadm
```

How can I display the shape on the map? I assume I have to leverage the sp package but I could not figure out how to do so.
Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can pass a `SpatialPolygons*` object to the `addPolygons` function as per Section 2.2 of the docs [here](http://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/).

For example (note that the following includes a ~11.4 MB download):

```
library(sp)
download.file('http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2/R/CAN_adm0.RData', f <- tempfile())
load(f)
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addPolygons(data=gadm, weight=2)
```

[image]

Note that GADM data can also be downloaded with the `getData` function in the `raster` package:

```
library(raster)
can <- getData('GADM', country='VAT', level=0)
```

---

**EDIT**

In response to the comments, I really like the lightweight polygon datasets that [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/) provides. Here's an example where I download the 1:50,000,000 countries shapefile (Admin 0) from Natural Earth, subset it to the current members of the Commonwealth of Nations, and plot those. The zipped shapefile is under 1 MB.

```
library(rgdal)
library(leaflet)

download.file(file.path('http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http/',
                        'www.naturalearthdata.com/download/50m/cultural',
                        'ne_50m_admin_0_countries.zip'), 
              f <- tempfile())
unzip(f, exdir=tempdir())

world <- readOGR(tempdir(), 'ne_50m_admin_0_countries', encoding='UTF-8')

commonwealth <- c("Antigua and Barb.", "Australia", "Bahamas", "Bangladesh", 
  "Barbados", "Belize", "Botswana", "Brunei", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cyprus",
  "Dominica", "Fiji", "Ghana", "Grenada", "Guyana", "India", "Jamaica", "Kenya",
  "Kiribati", "Lesotho", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Malta", "Mauritius",
  "Mozambique", "Namibia", "Nauru", "New Zealand", "Nigeria", "Pakistan", "Papua
  New Guinea", "Rwanda", "St. Kitts and Nevis", "Saint Lucia", "St. Vin. and
  Gren.", "Samoa", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Solomon Is.",
  "South Africa", "Sri Lanka", "Swaziland", "Tanzania", "Tonga", "Trinidad and
  Tobago", "Tuvalu", "Uganda", "United Kingdom", "Vanuatu", "Zamibia")

leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
  addPolygons(data=subset(world, name %in% commonwealth), weight=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you jbaums!  This works. You are right however, the size is very big and slows my process time significantly (I aim at showing several specific countries). Is there a lighter version of countries' polygons that I could use this way? Best regards!

Comment: @cho7tom - [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/) is great for this, see my edit.

Comment: Regarding process time, I noticed the `smoothFactor` in `addPolygon`, which says "how much to simplify the polyline on each zoom level (more means better performance and less accurate representation)". Perhaps that would help performance?