# How to plot polygons on leaflet using R?

Tags: r, leaflet, spatial, polygons

I have a simple problem that I am facing while in try to plot a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame on top of Leaflet using R. My code is as below:

```
leaflet() %>%
    addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
    setView(lng = -80.8858673, lat = 41.1450276, zoom = 5) %>%
    addPolygons(data = SPDF, weight = 2, color = ~colorQuantile("red", SPDF$id)(id))
```

Where SPDF is my SpatialPolygonsDataFrame.

When I execute this code it **"PLOTS NOTHING"** but only the base map. I have been searching around and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29118059/display-spatialpolygonsdataframe-on-leaflet-map-with-r) is similar but it doesn't have this issue.

In order to plot the polygons I have been following [this](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shapes.html) link.

The problem seems to be simple but it has consumed allot of time for me. Looking forward for the suggestions. Thanks for the time.

> NOTE: SPDF contains data exported from OSM, which means the coordinates (of POLYGONS) are without the decimal points as it is in the OSM data.

Comment: we can't test your code, but maybe you could start by adding a color argument in your addPolygons() expression ; (color = ~colorQuantile(...)

Comment: Yes I already tried this and now updated the above code as well. Still the same problem. :(

Comment: MLavoie can it be because of the latitude and longitude in my SPDF, they are without the decimal points as I imported data from OSM?

Comment: it's possible but without having access to your dataset it's hard to know

Comment: You can find my SPDF at this link:  http://www.filedropper.com/showdownload.php/spdf

Comment: Just execute load("SPDF.Rda") to get it in R

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, I have been able to figure out the problem myself. The problem is in **projections** and the **CRS (Coordinate Reference System)**.

Default proj4string was not properly set at the first place and in result of which the coordinates were not realistic (without the decimal point). Therefore, first I set the default proj4string of my SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(SPDF):

```
SPDF@proj4string <-CRS("+init=epsg:3857")
```

After setting this I provided the projection as following:

```
SPDF <- spTransform(SPDF,  CRS("+ellps=WGS84 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))
```

And now when I execute the following leaflet lines of code, it works perfectly.

```
leaflet() %>%
    addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
    setView(lng = -80.8858673, lat = 41.1450276, zoom = 5) %>%
    addPolygons(data = SPDF, weight = 2, color = ~colorQuantile("red", SPDF$osm_id)(osm_id))
```

In order to solve this I followed the discussion on [this](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/139) page.

I hope this works for others who are facing the same problem. Though still I am not an expert of projections and cartography, therefore, it would be great if someone may recommend some necessary information to understand such issues. Thanks all for the time.

PS: Make sure you have included the necessary packages such as leaflet, sp, magrittr etc.

Comment: Thanks bud, The `spTransform` was the only line missing.